# Missing disk space on Ubuntu server

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, 17.10, disk-usage, vps

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 (GNU/Linux 4.13.0-17-generic x86_64) on VPS and can't install anything 'You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/' (already cleared with autoclean) and /home is reporting to be full although there is only 144MB total of files.

```
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/vda: 25 GiB, 26843545600 bytes, 52428800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1fa5af5a

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/vda1  *        2048 44037759 44035712  21G 83 Linux
/dev/vda2       44037760 52426367  8388608   4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME   FSTYPE  SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sr0           1024M
vda             25G
├─vda1 ext4     21G /
└─vda2 swap      4G [SWAP]

 df -h --total
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
 tmpfs           395M   27M  369M   7% /run
 /dev/vda1       4.6G  4.3G     0 100% /
 tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
 tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
 tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
 tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
 tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/0
 total            12G  4.3G  6.9G  39% -
```

/dev/vda1 should be 21G total but df displays total of 12G and 100% usage, is there a problem with partitions or why isn't there any space left ?

SOLVED: use resize2fs /dev/vda1.

Comment: Run `sudo du -hs /var/log`

Comment: sudo du -hs /var/log
30M     /var/log

Comment: Is the root directory that it's full `/`, therefore, `/home` and everything else in the `/` partition won't have space.  I would delete the .deb files in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and it does look like there is a problem with the size of `/dev/vda1`

Comment: I found the solution, I had to use resize2fs /dev/vda1 to grow the partition.

Comment: might help: https://puvox.software/blog/solution-clean-full-disk-space-by-dev-vda1/